# What are some applications of arithmetic dynamics?

Tags: dynamical-systems, applications, arithmetic-dynamics

In classical real or complex dynamics, we iterate over the reals or complex numbers. One application of this, among many, is the discrete [logistic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map) for population growth.

In [arithmetic dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_dynamics), we iterate polynomial or rational maps over, for instance, finite fields, the rationals or a $p$-adic field. (Not an exhaustive list.)

Franco Vivaldi has investigated round-off errors in computer arithmetic using $p$-adic numbers. (See [http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~fvivaldi/research/](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/%7Efvivaldi/research/) for more information.)

What are some other applications of arithmetic dynamics?

Answer (score 2):

There are many applications, in particular to cryptography. There is a book [Applied Algebraic Dynamics](https://www.degruyter.com/view/title/32328);
see also the articles [T-functions revisited: new criteria for bijectivity/transitivity](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10623-012-9741-z) and [Secure cloud computations: Description of (fully)homomorphic ciphers within the P-adic model of encryption](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.07699).

Biology: [Automaton model of protein: Dynamics of conformational and functional states](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0079610716301663?casa_token=_5mm9WGYAi8AAAAA:1gLFih7xefcOSAzJN5qcCamfPGJtqXquZ3RzfuyAtvE92lvAfzfjnc3mMo3Xh8WxA_beiIcq-w)

Cognition and psychology:

A.Yu. Khrennikov, Human subconscious as the $p$-adic dynamical system. *Journal of Theoretical Biology*, 193, 179-196 (1998).

D. Dubischar, M. Gundlach, O. Steinkamp, A.Yu. Khrennikov,
A $p$-adic model for the process of thinking disturbed by physiological and information noise. *Journal of
Theoretical Biology*, 197, 451-467 (1999).

A.Yu. Khrennikov, *Information Dynamics in Cognitive, Psychological, Social and Anomalous
Phenomena*, Springer-Science + Business Media, B.Y., Dordrecht, NL, 2004.

Albeverio S, Khrennikov A and Kloeden P E  Memory retrieval as a $p$-adic dynamical system
*BioSystems* *49* 105--115 (1999).

Khrennikov, A. (2002). Classical and Quantum Mental Models and Freud's Theory of Unconscious Mind.
Växjö, SWE: Växjö University Press.

A.Yu. Khrennikov, Modelling of psychological behavior on the basis of ultrametric mental space:
Encoding of categories by balls. *P-Adic Numbers, Ultrametric Analysis, and Applications*, 2, 1-20 (2010).

Comment: I have edited the post for readability. If I have inadvertently changed something, please roll back or edit using the [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3814325/edit) link under your post/

Answer (score 1):

[Pollard's Rho algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm) (and its variations) for factoring an integer $N$ essentially rely on the structure revealed by repeated iteration of a polynomial mod $N$. As far as I recall it remains one of the fastest algorithms for finding small factors of composite $N$.

Answer (score 0):

[Monomial dynamical systems over finite fields](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0605439.pdf) by Colón-Reyes, Jarrah, Laubenbacher and Sturmfels mentions some applications of dynamics over finite fields in the introduction:

> Finite dynamical systems are time-discrete dynamical systems on finite state sets. Well-known
> examples include cellular automata and Boolean networks, which have found broad applications in
> engineering, computer science, and, more recently, computational biology. (See, e.g., [15; 1; 7; 19]
> for biological applications.) More general multi-state systems have been used in control theory
> [11; 20; 22; 23], the design and analysis of computer simulations [4; 2; 3; 18].